# Android support library 23.2.0 Horrible layout after update the library (desperate)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-appcompat

after update the version 23.2.0 of the appcompat, when I first run the application I find that the screen looks horrible, all the layout looks horrible in all activities in the app.

[image: The screen]

I have to uninstall the application and install it again to work well.

What can be ?

I'm desperate

Comment: Uh...  Your XML went wonky?

Comment: You will have better luck getting help if you can provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: but if i unnistall the app, and reinstall the app, then all works fine and the layouts shows well, is not xml problem.

Comment: Are you using a `RecyclerView`? 23.2 added support for auto-measurement and could be causing some issues if you're using `match_parent` when you should be using `wrap_content`.

Comment: yes i use the recyclerview, but not in the screen of the image, the screen of the image only contains a cardview with a button and a label inside.

Comment: i repeat, if i unninstall te app then works fine, this application works in all api > 10 without problem, the problem was today when i update the app compat in android studio and launch the application and surprise this problem.

Comment: the xml is fine, from the preview in android studio show me the layout perfectly, the problem is when i install this version above an app that is using the previous version of appcompat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the problem, it is the THEME of the application.

I have defined several themes in my app (styles.xml), I give the user to select some of them, and when the user select a color theme, i save the ID of the theme in a SharedPreferences and i assign the theme to the activity with setTheme(int) but something happened in the latest version of appcompat that the id i saved do not match and do not exist anymore. I'll have to save something else and not the id(int) of the theme

I realized that when i delete the "data" from the application and everything worked fine, because when i deleted the data the sharedpreferences is deleted too.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem a few days ago. This is because the new support library have new changes for the RecyclerView and the most important for your case is the following:

> RecyclerView.LayoutManager no longer ignores some RecyclerView.LayoutParams settings, such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction.
>
> Note: These lifted restrictions may cause unexpected behavior in your layouts. Make sure you specify the correct layout parameters.

So you should review your .xml in order to use the correctly height and width that before was ignoring it.

You can see more of the changes in this new version of the library [here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: there is no recyclerview in that screen of the image.

Comment: Did you clean your project, build gradle and remove build folder? Maybe is caching something old.

Comment: yes i tried that, the problem was the themes...see my solution.